# Getting error when trying to install POS on Localhost : Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context

Tags: php, sql, localhost

I am trying to install opensourcepos from https://github.com/jekkos/opensourcepos

But I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in   D:\Xampp\htdocs\opensourcepos\application\helpers\locale_helper.php on line 67
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Compile Error

Message: Can't use method return value in write context

Filename: helpers/locale_helper.php

Line Number: 67

Backtrace:
```

I followed instructions, this is a brand new install, I'm at a loss...

I'm on WIndows 7, using Localhost with Xampp

The line 67 is question is this one:

```
if (empty($config->item('thousands_separator')))
```

When I comment it out, the site loads, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

check readme txt

- You are getting following error `Message: Can't use method return value in write context` saying that you are probably using PHP7 which is not completely supported yet. Check your hosting configuration to verify whether you have a supported PHP version installed

Comment: Makes sense, I'll check it out